# Proposition about Euclidean distance and open ball

Tags: euclidean-geometry

About Euclidean space ($n$-dimensional)

$d_n(x,y)$ is Euclidean distance between $x$ and $y$.

For any $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$
, $B(a,r) := \left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n : d_n(a,x)<r \right\rbrace$.

For any $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $R>0$
, $B(b,R) := \left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n : d_n(b,x)<R \right\rbrace$.

Proposition ;

If $d_n(a,b)<R+r$ holds, then there exists c such that $c\in B(b,R) \cap B(a,r)$.

I drawn a picture and I found that such $c$ exists between $a$ and $b$.
However, I couldn't represent such $c$ as a formula ($c=\ldots$).

How should I represent such $c$ as a formula?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Consider the line segment between $a, b$ and the point on that line splitting the line segment in a ratio of $r:R$.

Comment: @player3236 $c=a+(b-a) \frac{r}{dn(a,b)}$ $\,\,$ or $\,\,$ $c=b+(a-b) \frac{R}{dn(a,b)}$ is OK?

Comment: For the denominator, instead of $d_n(a,b)$, it should be $r+R$.

Comment: However, when $c=a+(b-a) \frac{r}{r+R}$, $\,\,$ does $\,\,$ $dn(b,c)<R$ $\,\,$ hold? I can't prove that $\,\,$ $dn(b,c)<R$ $\,\,$ holds.